# API not creating smart trade using 3commas API

Tags: python, json

I am trying to create a smart trade using the 3commas API. I tried to create the smart trade but failed to so. I used their available API but I am very new to Python and API so I wrote this code but it is not correctly working. Can you help me to figure out the real issue. I searched for this error on internet but no found so much things and what I found I did not understand.

```py
import requests
import json

with open('config.json', 'r') as file:
    json_ = file.read()
sec = json.loads(json_)

# Replace with your 3commas API credentials
API_KEY = sec['api_key']
API_SECRET = sec['api_signature']

# Define the JSON data for the smart trade
with open('signal.json', 'r') as file:
    json_response = json.loads(file.read())

signal_data = {
    "account_id": sec['account_id'],
    "pair": json_response['pair'],
    "leverage": {
        "enabled": True,
        "type": "isolated",
        "value": json_response['leverage']
    },
    "position": {
        "type": "buy",
        #"order_type": "market",
        "units": {
            "value": sec['units_to_buy']
        },
        "price": {
            "value": json_response['entry_price']
        },
        "conditional": {
            "price": {
                "value": json_response['entry_price']
            },
            "price_type": "ask",
            "order_type": "limit",
            "trailing": {
                "enabled": False
            }
        }
    },
    "take_profit": {
        "enabled": True,
        "steps": [
            {
                "order_type": "market",
                "volume": str((int(json_response['take_profit'][0]['volume'].replace('%','')))/100),
                "price": {
                    "type": "bid",
                    "value": json_response['take_profit'][0]['price']
                },
                "trailing": {
                    "enabled": False
                }
            },
            {
                "order_type": "market",
                "volume": str((int(json_response['take_profit'][1]['volume'].replace('%','')))/100),
                "price": {
                    "type": "bid",
                    "value": json_response['take_profit'][1]['price']
                },
                "trailing": {
                    "enabled": False
                }
            },
            {
                "order_type": "market",
                "volume": str((int(json_response['take_profit'][2]['volume'].replace('%','')))/100),
                "price": {
                    "type": "bid",
                    "value": json_response['take_profit'][2]['price']
                },
                "trailing": {
                    "enabled": False
                }
            },
            {
                "order_type": "market",
                "volume": str((int(json_response['take_profit'][3]['volume'].replace('%','')))/100),
                "price": {
                    "type": "bid",
                    "value": json_response['take_profit'][3]['price']
                },
                "trailing": {
                    "enabled": False
                }
            },
            {
                "order_type": "market",
                "volume": str((int(json_response['take_profit'][4]['volume'].replace('%','')))/100),
                "price": {
                    "type": "bid",
                    "value": json_response['take_profit'][4]['price']
                },
                "trailing": {
                    "enabled": False
                }
            },
            {
                "order_type": "market",
                "volume": str((int(json_response['take_profit'][5]['volume'].replace('%','')))/100),
                "price": {
                    "type": "bid",
                    "value": json_response['take_profit'][5]['price']
                },
                "trailing": {
                    "enabled": False
                }
            },
            {
                "order_type": "market",
                "volume": str((int(json_response['take_profit'][6]['volume'].replace('%','')))/100),
                "price": {
                    "type": "bid",
                    "value": json_response['take_profit'][6]['price']
                },
                "trailing": {
                    "enabled": False
                }
            },
            {
                "order_type": "market",
                "volume": str((int(json_response['take_profit'][7]['volume'].replace('%','')))/100),
                "price": {
                    "type": "bid",
                    "value": json_response['take_profit'][7]['price']
                },
                "trailing": {
                    "enabled": False
                }
            },
            {
                "order_type": "market",
                "volume": str((int(json_response['take_profit'][8]['volume'].replace('%','')))/100),
                "price": {
                    "type": "bid",
                    "value": json_response['take_profit'][8]['price']
                },
                "trailing": {
                    "enabled": False
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "stop_loss": {
        "enabled": True,
        "breakeven": False,
        "order_type": "limit",
        "price": {
            "value": json_response['stop_loss']['price']
        },
        "conditional": {
            "price": {
                "type": "ask"
            },
            "price_value": 0,
            "price_percent": 0,
            "trailing": {
                "enabled": False
            }
        },
        "timeout": {
            "enabled": False
        }
    },
    #"account_id": account_id,  # Replace with the appropriate account ID
    "note": "Smart trade created through API"
}

# Define the API endpoint for creating a smart trade
endpoint = 'https://api.3commas.io/public/api/v2/smart_trades'

# Set up the API request headers
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'APIKEY': API_KEY,
    'Signature': API_SECRET
}

data = json.dumps(signal_data)

# Send the API request to create a smart trade
response = requests.post(endpoint, data, headers=headers)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Smart trade created successfully!")
else:
    print(f"Failed to create smart trade. Error: {response.text}")
```

However, when I run the script, I get the following error:

> Failed to create smart trade. Error: {"error":"signature_invalid","error_description":"Provided signature is invalid"}

Here is the original API documentation: [3commas api](https://github.com/3commas-io/3commas-official-api-docs/blob/master/smart_trades_v2_api.md).
I will be thankful to you if you can help.